# Href in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angular... I have some links of the variety `<a href='/foo/bar'/>` and I would like this to get routed to my rails controller as opposed to handled by angular.

I saw two solutions posted on stack overflow: setting target="_self" and this

```
app.run(function($location, $rootElement) {
  $rootElement.off('click');
});
```

The target attribute works OK but is not an ideal solution for me as I have some anchors generated by third-party gems. However, I am not able to get the second solution to work:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'

I have tried to provide a JS fiddle here -- http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/100/
(the href itself is not a very good example as I don't have a rails controller). Could someone help me figure out how to fix/debug the rootElement issue?

Comment: But do you also use routes from the Angular routing system? Do you mix Rails and Angular routing so to say?

Comment: maxdec, I do not have any Angular routes so far. I am still trying to figure out the proper way to "mix" things. So far the routing stays on the rails side; all json calls to refresh data go through Angular but full page reloads go to the Rails controllers (because I started with an existing rails app). Still trying to find good tutorials/articles on best-practices to mix the two -- pointers appreciated if you know good ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a new directive, to handle these special  tags.
Set this newly created directive to have a priority higher than 0 and to be terminal=true so the default  [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aa) won't run.

You can find more information about [Directives on Angular's documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)